# Regex for alphanumeric and maxlength

Tags: jquery, regex

I have made an expression that validates for alphanumeric characters

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
```

I also want to restrict the input to only 8 characters in same expression. How can I do that.
Thanks.

Here's my code sample

```
$('#coupon_code').bind('keypress', function (event) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,8}$");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
           event.preventDefault();
           return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: you are validating it in the keypress handler... and is validating only the entered key not the complete value of the input

Comment: What is the appropriate handler that I shall use in this case

Comment: for maxlength why don't you use the maxlength attribute

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5L9rd/1/

Comment: I am using the maxlength attribute but the set of users that will be using this are found to be trying to alter inputs through inspect element. I can do php validation but I was hoping if there was any way I can have it with regex. Thanks anyways

Comment: The regex is doing what it's supposed to do. You're just not supplying the appropriate input.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$");
```

The`{8}` tells it to only match exactly 8 characters.

Comment: And how is that different from the OP's question? (Note that OP's code accepts lengths of above 8 as well)

Comment: @Jery `{0,8}` will match between 0 and 8 digits, but `{8}` will match only exactly 8 characters.

Comment: You haven't read my comment completely. `{0,8}` also allowed more than 8 characters in OP's case.